# Linking two pages using JSP

Tags: jsp

So, I am trying to use JSP to create a set of webpages. I want to link two pages so that if the user clicks a button in one page, it will trigger an event in the other page. Is there an efficient way to do this?

I was taking a look at creating cookies and/or sessions. Any suggestions on these two methods? Thanks

Edit: The second page that is affected by the button click on the first page should already be open. I do not want a new tab to come up when I click the button on the first page. If the responding page is not open, nothing should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it are two independent pages, your best bet is to use either HTTP push (read on about "Comet") or Ajax poll. I only question why you were explicitly asking for linking **two** pages (and not three or more), so those pages must be somehow related to each other. If the second page is actually opened by for example Javascript `window.open()`, then you can make use of the `window` instance to access the second page and the `window.opener` property to access the parent page from the second page.

JSP as being a view technology can't do much for you here since it is just there to generate and send all the necessary HTML/CSS/JS, if not with help of taglibs and/or EL to access the "backend" Java code.